# python set.remove behavior and other builtins

Tags: python, set

In Python 2.7.x

```
In [21]: s = set([-1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0]).remove(-1)

In [22]: type(s)
Out[22]: NoneType
```

and

```
In [23]: s = set([-1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0])

In [24]: type(s)
Out[24]: set

In [25]: s.remove(-1)

In [26]: type(s)
Out[26]: set

In [27]: s
Out[27]: set([0])
```

Why does function chaining not work as expected in the above example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

generally, with python builtins, if the method modifies the object, it returns `None` to make it absolutely explicit that the object was modified **in place**.  In this case, `set.remove` modifies the set in place, so by convention, it should return `None`.

You'll see the same behavior with `list.remove` or `list.append` or `set.add` for example.

This comes as a shock to people coming from different languages where it is common for a method to mutate the object and (effectively) to return `self`.  It's convenient in that it allows methods to be chained nicely...  But, the core python dev's have chosen a different path because they believe (and I agree) that in the long run, it leads to cleaner more obvious code.  I would advise you to use python's convention in your own python code (but of course, you're free to disregard that advice completely).

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time! (...and I am taking your advice on using python like python is meant to be used. :-)

Answer (score 4):

`set.remove()` does not return a set with the removed items, it removes them in place. As it does this, the function will return `None`. So technically you are doing `s = None` in your first example.

Comment: Your's is the most laconic, and to-the-point answer! Thanks a lot! I would choose your answer over all others if this site was only between us. I will choose @mgilson's answer however, because for readers that are likely to come this way and are not familiar with significance of "in-place" in the answer's context are likely to miss the point, simply because it is not emboldened.

Comment: @anicake That's fine :). Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

```
s = set([-1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

`remove` returns `None`. You can confirm that by printing the type of the return value from `remove` like this

```
print type(s.remove(-1))
```

you will get

```
<type 'NoneType'>
```

So, basically you are setting `None` to `s`.

Comment: Thanks very much for answering. After reading all the answers that exist as I'm writing this, I think I understand from @mgilson 's answer better as they mention "in-place" modification as against, returning the object. But thanks.